# Start pure X11 with fullscreen remote-viewer to started KVM instance

Tags: x11, kvm

Intention is to start LightDM session with only VM and connecting app working, so no other apps will interfere with its usage.
I've created `.xsession` which starts KVM domain and `remote-viewer` in fullscreen mode.
KVM content are two displays with resolution matching my OS resolution.
Problem is that `remote-viewer` starts with top-bar visible moving content those X pixel to below bottom edge. When I manually move `remote-viewer` windows by those X pixels up - then it looks acceptable.

```
#!/bin/bash
#start VM machine
sudo virsh start debian_vm_1

while true
do 
  [[ `pgrep kvm | wc -l` -ne 0 ]] && break; 
  sleep 0.5s;
done
xrandr --output DP-1-8 --primary --right-of DP-1-1-8 --output eDP-1 --right-of DP-1-8
remote-viewer --auto-resize never -k --kiosk-quit on-disconnect spice://localhost:5900
```

As you see - trigger to close session is closing viewer.

- how to make `remote-viewer` hide top-bar? setting fullscreen works in i3 WM (top-bar hides nicely), but in pure X11 doesn't
- how to move 'remote-viewer' in a delayed way?

PS: As a workaround I could start i3 with default profile and use it to handle windows positioning.

Comment: `[[ \`pgrep kvm | wc -l\` -ne 0 ]]` should probably be just `pgrep -q kvm`; see also [useless use of `wc`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc)